# Getting incorrect results from a function that calculates the natural logarithm

Tags: javascript, math, linear-algebra

I'm making a `JavaScript` function that calculates the **natural logarithm** for the passed number using **Taylor series**, but I'm getting incorrect results.
I know there's a built-in method in the `Math` object to perform this task, but the function I've been working on has a threshold.

```
function ln(num,threshold) {
    "use strict";
    var i;
    var result=0;
    if (num<=0) {
        result="Error:Cannot Calculate The Natural Logarithm For A Negative Number";
    }
    else {
        for (i=1;i<=threshold;i++) {
            result+=Math.pow(-1,i-1)*Math.pow(num-1,i)/i;
        }
        result = result.toFixed(20);
    }
    return result;
}

ln(3,17); //output is 5038.54220028337658732198
```

Comment: why are you using `arguments` over named parameters?

Comment: @SterlingArcher in fact sir i'am using it in a project "not a homework or something like that" and i want things to look complicated.

Comment: cluttered is not the same as complicated

Comment: I am not jealous of your replacement.

Comment: why would you want it to look complicated? isn't that the exact opposite of what we're supposed to be striving for?

Comment: is it a bad practice to use `arguments`?

Comment: Yes it is a bad practice, use named parameters instead :)

Comment: thank you all guys for the advice..
i've removed the `arguments` object and switched to **named parameters**.

Comment: Use `-Math.pow(1-num,pow)/i` to get the same result with half the effort. Do not use your function for anything serious where the logarithm value is used. If you think this might be faster, think again as `Math.pow(x,y)` is a more or less expansive wrapper around `exp(y*log(x))` (where `exp` and `log` are the more direct functions from the run-time engine resp. FPU, in the latter case possibly with basis `2`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not using the taylor series correctly. If you read the wikipedia page it specifies the following:

"The series converges to the natural logarithm (shifted by 1) whenever  -1 < x < 1 ."

So you're using 3, which doesn't fall within that range so that's why it's not converging.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm#Derivative.2C_Taylor_series
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm#/media/File:LogTay.svg
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_series

And indeed running `ln(2, 17)` spits out a far more appropriate number.